# How do i fetch dynamically created text box values in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have doubt regarding dynamically created textbox values in JSP file. My files contains HTML and Javascript (home.jsp) and JSP (abc.jsp).

In this example I can fetch values only initially created textboxes, I can't fetch values from dynamically created textboxes. How do I fetch values from each dynamically created textboxes at run time in the JSP file?  How do I fetch total number of textboxes created at run time?

home.jsp

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var addDiv = $('#addinput');
        var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

        $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" size="20" name="p_new_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="I am New" /><input type="text" id="p_new1" size="20" name="p_new1_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="I am New" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Remove</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
            i++;
            document.getElementById('raj').value = i;
            return false;
        });

        $('#remNew').live('click', function() {
            if (i > 2) {
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                i--;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="abc.jsp" method="post">
        <h2>Dynammically Add Another Input Box</h2>
        <div id="addinput">
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="p_new" size="20" name="p_new" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><input type="text" id="p_new1" size="20" name="p_new1" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /><a href="#" id="addNew">Add</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

abc.jsp

```
<%            
    String name = request.getParameter("p_new");
    String name1 = request.getParameter("p_new1");
    String name2 = request.getParameter("p_new_[0]");
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(name1);
    System.out.println(name2);
%>
```

Comment: BalusC i didn't understand that question. please provide solution to this problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide same names to input fields

then use `getParameterValues('p_new')`  it will return String array

**Update**

if your are sending multiple input then first, second  i.e ur static input too rename with `p_new`

then you are able to access using `getParameterValues('p_new')`

your static name not match with dynamic created input

Comment: An exception occurred processing JSP page /abc.jsp at line 23 String name2=request.getParameterValues("p_new_")[0];

Comment: u have appended `i` to `p_new_`, you need to access it 

like `p_new_ + i`

Comment: try name2=request.getParameter("p_new_2"); to get name2 and so onn..for name3,name4...replace 2 with respective OR iterate it by sending count

Comment: thanku so much working thanks a lot shantaram